# Ubuntu 14.04 - cups printing takes a long time to initially load

Tags: printing

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and while the cupsd service does eventually load, it takes roughly 20 seconds after boot until it shows up under ps aux. I had the same problem with 12.04. Is there any way to start this service faster or load it before other services?

Thanks.. Mark

Comment: What about this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21378/how-can-i-make-sure-one-upstart-job-starts-before-other-upstart-jobs