# How to make sure OpenVPN service is started first (before other services) on 14.04?

Tags: vpn, upstart, openvpn

I'm running OpenVPN as an upstart script on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. I have an openvpn.conf file in the /etc/init/ folder.

It works perfectly, OpenVPN starts on system start and connects to VPN server. However, I also run Deluge and some other services that I need explicitly to allow connection to Internet only through VPN.
Deluged is also started as with an upstart script, and actually it is working perfectly fine.

One thing I'm not sure: what is the sequence of of starting these services during the system start? I need OpenVPN to start before Deluge service. I really read a lot about start-on parameters, but I'm not sure if it is enough to put this into the upstart script.

I see a similar questions here: [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21378/how-can-i-make-sure-one-upstart-job-starts-before-other-upstart-jobs)
According to this, it can not be done with upstart script, only if I use a "wait script"?

What do I need to put in openvpn.conf and deluged.conf upstart scripts to make this work?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The numerical order of system services is displayed in */etc/rc2.d* where higher number means later, you can change thos numbers.
Also you could add delay in seconds option into deluged startup script, example

```
    sleep 10
```

Comment: Thank you! I will look at the suggestions. It is so much easier with systemd, but I need to resolve this with upstart.